# MySQL "subtable" in a table?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a structure where there is a table with a userid and username and each userid gets it's own table. I wondered if there is a way to add a third column with the type being it's own table. If not what is the best way to go about this.

Comment: This idea is a poor design. Explain what you want to store in those "other tables" and we can help you with a better design for your database.

Comment: Create a table with the userid as a foreign key.

Comment: See normalisation

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to saving user attributes is create a `usermeta` table. attention to following structure:

## Users:

```
user_id | user_name | user_mail
--------------------------------
1       | ali       | me@ali.com
2       | mahdi     | me@mahdi.ir
```

## Usermeta

```
meta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value
-----------------------------------------
10      | 1       | points   | 10
11      | 1       | address  | london
12      | 2       | address  | iran
13      | 2       | is_vip   | true
```

In this form you can add any attribute for any user that you want. it's flexible to save no-predefined attributes. in this structure you have not redundancy of data.

You can use [dynamic column](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/dynamic-columns-tutorial-part-1-introduction) also.

Comment: FWIW, whe using an EAV, I like to split tables according to data type - so, I might have a table of date type things, a table of integer type things, and a table of string type things.

Comment: This is the way also WordPress does it. Its a great way to go in many cases.

Comment: @Strawberry that's correct. but it's a general structure. if you consider data type, create multi usermeta tables!

Comment: @Blackbam Yes, it's WordPress table structure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would be a good thing to do. You'd better create a table for your users and then for example a settings table with a UserId column.

This way you can reference to the user specific properties using joins.
For example:

Table Users with columns: UserId and Username

Table Settings with columns: UserId, Setting, Value

If you then want to get those combined you could use this sql:

```
SELECT Users.UserId, Username, Setting, Value 
FROM Users  
    INNER JOIN Settings ON Settings.UserId=Users.UserId
```